# How does the SSH-CA Authentication works in detail?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I know how to Setup the whole SSH-CA Stuff, with Configuration of sshd and signing of the Keys. But what i wondering is, how does the Authentication works in detail?

Like it is described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-ssh-encryption-and-connection-process) in the last Chapter for the PublicKey Authentication in detail. I wasn`t able to find an Answer.

I Imagine it works something like that:

1. Serverside: Checks if the Principal in the signedCertificate is stored in the validPrincipals file, check validity of the signedCertificate and verify if the Public Key of the CA which is in the signedCertificate matches with the Trusted one configured on the Server.
2. Serverside: Generate a randomNumber and encrypt it with the provided PublicKey and sent it back to the Client.
3. Clientside: Decrypt the randomNumber and generate an MD5 Sum with the RandomNumber and the SharedSessionKey, sent it Back to the Server
4. Serverside: also creates the MD5 Hashsum with the randomNumber and SharedSessionKey and check if it match with the recieved one and allow or block access

Comment: If you want details on how the authentication part works, this is the reference: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4252.  But this was long before the system with certificates was introduced.

Comment: The document you quote is about generic ssh working, not specifically about using a CA (instead of "bare" keys). A certificate is a public key with some metadata, including a signature made by another key (the CA or an intermediate). Anyone possessing the corresponding public key can check that the signature is legit. If that goes through then the public key contained in the certificate is accepted as legitimate and goes forward. The rest after it you describe is making sure the client has the corresponding private key to the public key offered, which is separate from how the key is accepted.

Comment: I am aware that the document pointed out the generic ssh stuff i just mentioned it as reference regarding what i want to know. I know that the additional metadata of an certificate (Principals, Validity and so on ) is used for authentification, but i was just wondering how the key itself gets validated, as the public one is not deposited on the server. So if i understand you correct, my assumption that the publickeyfrom the signature will taken is correct? Is there an updated RFC available which describes the process?

Comment: I see https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/src/usr.bin/ssh/PROTOCOL.certkeys?annotate=HEAD explaining this case but this is certainly not enough

Comment: Ah awesome, thank you for that. I just checked the [Applicationcode](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/auth2-pubkey.c?rev=1.94&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) in comparison with the DebugLog Serverside, but to understand everything it is not easy.

I assume beside to read the applicationcode and inteprete it, there is no other documentation which explains it propperly. *sigh*

Comment: Look also at the "AUTHENTICATION" section of https://man.openbsd.org/sshd.8 and later the discussion on "cert-authority".

Comment: Which Discussion you refer to ?

Comment: The mentions of "cert-authority" at multiple places in the link given